# How to create a Pinterest board with all images from an URL

Tags: pinterest

I use Pinterest to announce my blog posts. Since I have a lot of pictures in my posts I'd like to create a Pinterest board including all pictures from one post.

I can do this by hand, but having 10+ images on one page makes this very tedious. Is there a way to automate this or at least make it less tedious?

I tried [pinthemall.net](http://pinthemall.net/) but this creates a single image of all images, not a board with all the images.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a bulk-load option for Pinterest.

Alternatives:  You could try installing the PinIt toolbar for your browser (instructions here).    Or add a Pin-It widget to your blog (choose the Any image option from here:   http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button).

These won't do quite what you want, but will make it easier to pin the individual images from your posts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I translated to german "pinwand" to album which isn't very precise. I fixed the mistake in the question.